# Function running confuse on VxWorks

Tags: vxworks

We're trying to use VxWorks' UDP multicast.
Using the command line (->), we call the initialization function with some parameters and the multicast runs successfully.

When I try to run this method from code, the initialization function returns OK (no errors), but does not initialize the multicast UDP port.

Is there a catch ?

Comment: You might want to put the function you're calling along with the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to be aware of is that the TCP/IP stack gets initialized **after** the rootTask completes.

The usrAppInit function runs in the context of the root task.  If you are invoking network stack elements in usrAppInit, things might not work.

Make sure you invoke your networking code from a task that has been spawned with a lower priority than the network stack (which runs at priority 50).